# Reading and writing in-memory data

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

In the following example, I am taking a struct that occupies 32 bytes in memory and writing that to a file and reading it back in -- i.e., serializing the data to a binary format:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _Person {
    char   name[20];
    int    age;
    double weight;
} Person;

int main(void)
{

    Person tom = (Person) {.name="Tom", .age=20, .weight=125.0};

    // write the struct to a binary file
    FILE *fout = fopen("person.b", "wb");
    fwrite(&tom, sizeof tom, 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);

    // read the binary data and set the person to that
    Person unknown;
    FILE *fin = fopen("person.b", "rb");
    fread(&unknown, sizeof unknown, 1, fin);
    fclose(fin);

    // confirm all looks ok
    printf("{name=%s, age=%d, weight=%f}", unknown.name, unknown.age, unknown.weight);

}
```

Note however that these are all values on the stack, and no pointers/indirection is involved. How might data be serialized to a file when, for example, multiple pointers can be involved, multiple variables may point to the same memory location, etc. Is this effectively what protocol buffers do?

Comment: You need to use a serialization format. Popular ones these days are JSON and XML.

Comment: Yes, this is also what Protocol Buffers does.

Comment: @Barmar right, I want to keep it in binary format though, so maybe the protobuf or something similar.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 this may help you https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers

Comment: Well... No. You are not serializing at all. You are writing the number of bytes taken by the struct out to a file (including any padding bytes). While this may work on the same compiler and same computer, it is not portable because the C standard does not specify if or where padding bytes go. That is up to individual compilers to implement. Serializing means writing each part of the struct out in a way that it can be portably read back in regardless of which compiler you happen to use and regardless of endianness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you want a binary file. I used to do it this way long ago. It's fine. It just breaks when you move to another platform or bitness. I'm teaching the old way because it's a good place to start. Newer ways are popular now because they keep working when changing platforms or bitnesses.

When writing records to the file I would use structs like this:

```
typedef struct _Person {
    char   name[20];
    int    age;
    double weight;
} Person;

typedef struct _Thing {
    char name[20];
};

typedef struct _Owner {
    int personId;
    int thingId;
} Owner;
```

See how the `Owner` structure has Id members. These are just indices into the arrays of the other structures.

These can be written out to a file one after another, usually prefixed by a single integer written directly that says how many records of each kind. The reader just allocates an array of structs with `malloc` big enough to hold them. As we add more items in memory we resize the arrays with `realloc`. We can (and should) also mark for deleting (say by setting the first character of name to 0) and reusing the record later.

The writer looks something like this:

```
void writeall(FILE *h, Person *allPeople, int nPeople, Thing *allThings, int nThings, Owner *allOwners, int nOwners)
{
    // Error checking omitted for brevity
    fwrite(&nPeople, sizeof(nPeople), 1, h);
    fwrite(allPeople, sizeof(*allPeople), nPeople, h);
    fwrite(&nThings, sizeof(nThings), 1, h);
    fwrite(allThings, sizeof(*allThings), nThings, h);
    fwrite(&nOwners, sizeof(nOwners), 1, h);
    fwrite(allOwners, sizeof(*allOwners), nOwners, h);
}
```

The reader in turn looks like this:

```
int writeall(FILE *h, Person **allPeople, int *nPeople, int *aPeople, Thing **allThings, int *nThings, int *aThings, Owner **allOwners, int *nOwners, int *aOwners)
{
    *aPeople = 0; // Don't crash on bad read
    *aThigns = 0;
    *aOwners = 0;
    *allPeople = NULL;
    *allThings = NULL;
    *allOwners = NULL;

    if (1 != fread(nPeople, sizeof(*nPeople), 1, h)) return 0;
    *allPeople = malloc(sizeof(**allPeople) * *nPeople);
    if (!allPeople) return 0; // OOM
    *aPeople = *nPeople;
    if (*nPeople != fread(*allPeople, sizeof(**allPeople), nPeople, h)) return 0;

    if (1 != fread(nThings, sizeof(*nThings), 1, h)) return 0;
    *allThings = malloc(sizeof(**allThings) * *nThings);
    if (!allThings) return 0; // OOM
    *aThings = *nThings;
    if (*nThings != fread(*allThings, sizeof(**allThings), nThings, h)) return 0;

    if (1 != fread(nOwners, sizeof(*nOwners), 1, h)) return 0;
    *allOwners = malloc(sizeof(**allOwners) * *nOwners);
    if (!allOwners) return 0; // OOM
    *aOwners = *nOwners;
    if (*nOwners != fread(*allOwners, sizeof(**allOwners), nOwners, h)) return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

There was an old technique for writing a heap arena directly to disk and reading it back again. I recommend never using it, and never storing pointers on disk. That way lies security nightmares.

When memory was cheap I would have talked about how to use block allocation and linked blocks to dynamically update the on-disk records partially; but now for problems you're going to encounter at this level I say don't bother, and just read the whole thing into RAM and write it back out again. Eventually you will learn databases, which handles that stuff for you.